# Minimizing the dependency on certain features in logistic regression

Tags: python, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, analysis

I have a dataset for a web business and I am trying to predict conversions (using logistic regression) and I want to figure out which features are the strongest predictors of conversions. The dataset has multiple features that show what the users think of the business and several other features that show customer profile (what device they use, what products they have bought...). The data is spread out across different business lines and contains users from different platforms (mobile,desktop users etc.). Each different business line and users from different platforms have different intrinsic conversion rates, how would i work against that so when I look at feature importance it wouldn't just tell me the business line and the device are the strongest predictors of conversions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking what normalization is and how it is accomplished or are you asking some to write the normalization code for you? Can you explain in words how to normalize the data the way you want?

Comment: I edited my initial post, thank you for the clarifying question.